# error importing tables in python

Tags: python, linker-errors, importerror, pytables

I have installed python 2.6, numpy 1.6.1, tables 2.3.1 y numexpr 2.0 under windows 32bits. However **import tables** gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\src\test\test6.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tables
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tables.file import File, openFile, copyFile
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 42, in <module>
    import numexpr
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numexpr\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from numexpr.expressions import E
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numexpr\expressions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from numexpr import interpreter
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Where did you get "tables" (I haven't heard of it)? Did you try reading their documentation? It looks like something was not installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to compile interpreter.c which isn't that easy in windows. Would it be ok if you used numexpr 1.4? You can use a precompiled installer that way http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/downloads/list